# Help Aunt Nora solve this puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking, visual

Aunt Nora has the following images which contain hints to objects used in the production of a specific substance. What is the substance?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! It might be a good idea to credit your image sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the lantern represents

> kerosene

and the second picture is a

> hydraulic press

which represents

> pressure

and the third picture is

> the chemical formula HCl for hydrochloric acid

All three of these things are used in the

> production of rocket fuel.

Comment: Was I right? If not, any hints?